# Android: how to set the number of items in a GridView

Tags: android

I only set the num columns in properties of a GridView. Nowhere to set the number of items

I google but only got some questions about how to fix the rows of GridView. I looking for in API GridView also, but there is no function to do that.

Someone teach me? Thanks

Comment: Check : https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: To set the number of items in your `GridView` I think that it's better to pass to your `GridView` only the items you want to show. I don't clearly understand your question

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the number of items directly on a grid view. This has to be done using its adapter and set the number of items in the adapter.

Usually a variable/array holding the items is created before an adapter is passed to the grid. This will populate the grid accordingly.

To be specific, this is the adapter function

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return "HOW MANY ITEMS YOU WANT TO SHOW";
    }
```

Comment: @Verru Thank you. Now, I can do that. Another question, can I fix the numbers of items in a row? My target is drawing the dynamic matrix 3x3, 4x4,... GridView is suitable for that? Or I should use TableLayout?

Comment: use can use to set number of column android:numColumns="4" in xml or if you require change dynamically it then use gridview.setNumColumns(n);

Comment: Like Hradesh said, you can use setNumberOfColumns(). If you want a 3x3, your columns shoud be 3 and the getCount() return value should be 9. GridView is perfectly suitable for that.

Comment: @HradeshKumar, Veeru: yes, I got it. Thanks both of you

Comment: Now, I have another problem: how to set the number of items in a row? 4X4 is Ok, however in case 5x5 only 4 items in a row? How to resize item to fit in a row. Thanks

Comment: If you are looking to resize the items, you should take a look at the getView() function in the adapter. Here you can customize your view.